# VLC - Windows 8 / 10 Store Version - How to disable subtitles by default

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, vlc-media-player, default-settings

I'm using the VLC app that is the Windows Store Version.

How do I go about disabling Subtitles on playback by default while still allowing the options during playback to select Subtitles?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I go about disabling Subtitles on playback by default while still allowing the options during playback to select Subtitles?

- Menu "Tools" > "Preferences" or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.
- Select "Subtitles / OSD" tab.
- Uncheck "Enable On Screen Display (OSD)".
- Press "Save".

  [image]

Comment: That is for the full version from the VLC website that i'm well aware on how to do, i'm asking for the version that is available in the Windows 8 / 10 Store which is a much more limited but efficient version if it can be done at all